# How to make UILocalNotification repeat like Alarm clock in Default clock app in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, clock, alarm

I have make Alarm clock like Alarm cock default in ios but I don't konw How to make UILocalNotification repeat like Alarm clock in Default clock app in ios. That mean alarm clock repeat certain days in a week.  Thanks

Repeat like image:
http://i594.photobucket.com/albums/tt22/hungknorton/RepeatClock.png

Comment: You will have to register a separate `UILocalNotification` for each day of the week.

Comment: In addition to @PartiallyFinite, you basically have to calculate the next alarm time (i.e. the NSDate of 7 a.m. of the next Friday), and set weekly repeat from there.

Comment: @He Shiming, thank for your comment. Can your write code here ?

Comment: See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Use `[notification setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit]`

Comment: @PartiallyFinite I think [notification setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit] just repeat alarm every week. If i need alarm repeat like image http://i594.photobucket.com/albums/tt22/hungknorton/RepeatClock.png . How to do that ?

Comment: You create a *separate* notification for each of the selected days of the week, so you would make one for Tuesday, one for Wednesday, and one for Friday, and make each one repeat every week.

Comment: Since NSWeekCalendarUnit is now deprecated, what's the proper replacement?